# How to deserialize type YearMonth (SpringBoot)

Tags: java, json, spring, types, deserialization

I have problem because when I have request with type YearMonth like this
`{"year":2019,"month":"JANUARY","monthValue":1,"leapYear":false}`
when starting controller which serve this request I have error

> "message": "JSON parse error: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, START_ARRAY] for java.time.YearMonth value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected one of [VALUE_STRING, START_ARRAY] for java.time.YearMonth value\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 7] (through reference chain: com.bbh.centrum.nav.api.EarnThruAdjustmentRequest[\"dates\"]->java.util.HashSet[0])",

Comment: You should probably include the `jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency for date/time serialization

Comment: I have, but doesn't work.

Comment: Could you also post your POJO for deserialization?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @Michlut Can you answer if you solved the problem?